# Windows LAF & ENTER as Focus Traversal Key

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, focus, look-and-feel

Alright so this is a weird one, since its working for other non-Windows PLAFs.

First of all, I'm setting my PLAF as:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
```

and then I add ENTER to be in the FORWARD traversal keys as:

```
Set<AWTKeyStroke> forSet = new HashSet<AWTKeyStroke>();
forSet.add(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().setDefaultFocusTraversalKeys(
KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS, forSet);
```

I tried them vice versa but didn't work as well.

Any clues?